# Spring Security, new session not being made even after opening a new tab

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, http, spring-security

this is my security config file

```
package com.example.tacohouse.configuration;
import com.example.tacohouse.model.User;
import com.example.tacohouse.repositories.UserRepository;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityCustomizer;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.servlet.util.matcher.MvcRequestMatcher;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerMappingIntrospector;
import static org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher.antMatcher;
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService(UserRepository userRepository){
        return username->{
            User user = userRepository.findByUsername(username);
            if(user!=null){
                return user;
            }
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User:\"" + username + "\" not found" );
        };
    }
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http, HandlerMappingIntrospector introspector) throws Exception{
        MvcRequestMatcher.Builder mvc = new MvcRequestMatcher.Builder(introspector);
        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests((auth)-> auth
                        .requestMatchers(mvc.pattern("/design") , mvc.pattern("/orders")).hasRole("USER")
                        .requestMatchers(mvc.pattern("/"), mvc.pattern("/**")).permitAll())
                .formLogin(form->
                        form
                                .loginPage("/login")
                                .defaultSuccessUrl(("/"),true));
        return http.build();
    }
    @Bean
    public WebSecurityCustomizer webSecurityCustomizer() {
        return (web) -> web.ignoring().requestMatchers(antMatcher("/h2-console/**"));
    }
}
```

when i open a new tab first time, it works fine and it prompts me to log in. But whenever i open a new tab after that, it doesnt create a new session but just use cookies to log me in directly.
Due to this i can't test if my log in is working or not.
I need to open a new chrome window every time i need to test log in mechanism.
Does it creates a browser session and stores my login info and automatically lets me enter every time or is it done by spring iteself and i need to set it in spring security?

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is due to how sessions are managed in web browsers and Spring Security.

**Browser Session Behavior:**
When you log in to your application in one tab, Spring Security creates a session and stores it as a cookie in your browser. Opening a new tab in the same browser shares cookies, which means the new tab is also aware of the session you've established. Thus, you're already authenticated in the new tab.

**Spring Security Default Session Management:**
By default, Spring Security uses a session management strategy that doesn't restrict sessions to a single browser tab. Therefore, when you open a new tab, you remain authenticated until the session expires or you log out.

If you want to force a new log in every time a new tab is opened (which might not be a great user experience), you'd need a custom session management strategy. To do so you can set the session to be stateless